# 'però' seguito da 'anzi'

Tags: phrase-request

Uno mi ha detto:

> La commissione europea deciderà sul DEF senza la Mogherini.

Io ho risposto:

> Non so quanto sia peggio, però.

Avrei anche voluto aggiungere 'anzi', così:

> Non so quanto sia peggio, però, anzi.

Domanda: È un costrutto corretto quel 'però, anzi' finale? O 'anzi' è superfluo, se non addirittura ridondante?

Comment: Che cosa intendevi? Potresti parafrasare? Qualcosa come “magari è pure meglio”?

Comment: Intendevo dire che se la Mogherini non partecipa alla valutazione del def è molto ma molto meglio.

Comment: Grazie, adesso l'aspetto linguistico è chiaro. Per quanto riguarda l'esempio specifico, già in almeno un'altra domanda ti è stato fatto notare che è meglio evitare di attingere ad esempi reali tratti dalla politica.

Comment: @DaG, però su altri siti SE, come ELU, vedo molti esempi tratti dai media che, incidentalmente, sono tratti da news politiche.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider È tuttavia relativamente semplice modificare un esempio venuto originariamente alla mente in riferimento alle vicende politiche in maniera tale da preservare il nocciolo della questione linguistica depurandola da elementi estranei e potenzialmente irritanti.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Il tuo esempio non è estratto però, poniamo, da un articolo di giornale, ma da una conversazione privata. Se si fosse trattato di una confidenza tra amici, non avresti fatto nomi e cognomi, ma solo messo in evidenza l'aspetto linguistico interessante, no? Credo sia il caso di fare lo stesso per questioni che coinvolgono opinioni su cui potremmo non concordare tutti.

Answer (score 5):

Nella lingua parlata (che è il tuo caso) è del tutto accettabile. In quella scritta forse è meglio evitare, perché è difficile capire il rapporto tra le parole (io ho dovuto leggerlo un paio di volte per capire l'intonazione giusta).